# dropping retweets in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

i've implement a class to store tweets:

```
class Twitter_User():
    def __init__(self,id,count=200):
        self.id = id
        self.count = count
    def get_tweets(self):
        store_tweets = api.user_timeline(self.id, count=self.count)
        simple_list = []
        for status in store_tweets:
            array = [status._json["text"], status._json["favorite_count"], status._json["created_at"],status._json["retweet_count"]]
            simple_list.append(array)
        data = pd.DataFrame(simple_list, columns=["Text", "Like", "Created at","Retweet"])
        return data
```

now i want remove by Text colums all retweets(text that starts with "RT"), how can i get this? with regex and apply or there is more simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [`str.startwith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html)

```
df[~df.text.str.startswith('RT')]
```

Comment: @LimeInTheCoconut then you need to show your sample data

Comment: ok now works sorry, in the init i put self.rt=True by default, and a condition if self.rt == False then df = df[~df.text.str.startswith('RT')]. Removing this condition and putting your code just before return data things seems works